# change images displayed from a array using function called from a click

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of three images. I want to call the function from `onClick`. Here's my code. I know can be done with jQuery but I'm just using plain JavaScript.

**JavaScript**

```
var myArray =    ["_images/taste_logo_130w.gif","_images/logo.gif", "_images/winery_sign.jpg"];
var current = 0;
function imageTimer() {
    if(current >= array.length) {
        documnent.getElementById("logo").src = array[current];
        current ++;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="_images/logo.gif" id="logo" width="192" height="237" onClick=setInterval("imageTimer()", 3000);  />
```

Comment: `if(current >= array.length)` should't it be lowerthen?

Comment: `setInterval` instead of Interval

Comment: At first, you shouldn't use inline event handler!
Second, you should use setTimeout instead! and if you want you can read more about [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) and [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).
[JavaScript: Bad Practices](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/javascript-bad-practices/)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps so?

```
function imageTimer() {
    if(current < array.length) {
        current++;
    }else{
        current = 0;
    }
    documnent.getElementById("logo").src = array[current];
}
```

or shorter:

```
   function imageTimer() {
        (current < array.length) ? current++ : current = 0;
        documnent.getElementById("logo").src = array[current];
    }
```

Comment: Or even shorter :) `documnent.getElementById("logo").src = array[current >= array.length ? 0 : current++];`

Answer (score 1):

(1)

```
if(current >= array.length) { // fail always
```

since **`current is 0`**  and **`array.length is 3`**

So above condition will fail always.

(2) what happens on 4th click, there is no image.  So better recycle it by resetting the value of current to zero.

Code:

```
var myArray =    ["_images/taste_logo_130w.gif","_images/logo.gif", "_images/winery_sign.jpg"];
var current = 0;
function imageTimer() {
    if(current <= array.length) {
        documnent.getElementById("logo").src = array[current];
        current ++;
    }
    else {
      current = 0;  //reset back to zero  on 4th click
    } 
}
```

Comment: and what happens with the picture on the 4-th, 8-th, 12-th[...] click? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have an array `myArray` but in the function you are calling the `.lenght` on `array` so change that to `myArray.lenght` and you have `array[current]` which should be `myArray[current]`. Your if condition will also always be false if you have `if(current >= myArray.lenght)` because (0 >= 3) is always false.

Try this:

```
var myArray =    ["_images/taste_logo_130w.gif","_images/logo.gif", "_images/winery_sign.jpg"];
var current = 0;
function imageTimer() {
  if(current < myArray.length) {
    documnent.getElementById("logo").src = myArray[current];
    current ++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

javascript:

```
  var myArray =    ["_images/
  taste_logo_130w.gif","_images/logo.gif",
  "_images/winery_sign.jpg"];
  var current;
  var timr;
  function imageTimer() {
  if(current < array.length) {
    documnent.getElementById
    ("logo").src = array[current];
    current ++;
  }
  else clearInterval(timr);
  }
```

html:

```
  <img src="_images/logo.gif" id="logo"
  width="192" height="237" onClick="timr=setInterval
  (function(){
   current=0;
   imageTimer();
   }, 3000);  "/>
```